# Why my inside divs went oustide the container div?

Tags: html, css

When I zoomed the browser, the **date** and **apa**  div went outside the **container** div. How to keep the **date/apa** div still inside the container even when zoomed? Sorry for asking simple question. Just a beginner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testeffect.css"/>
    </head>

     <body>


        <div id="header">


            <div id="container">
                <div id="date">
                    <p>18 Jamadilawal 1434H<br> Saturday, 30th March 2013<br><p>
                </div>

                <div id="apa">
                <p>18 Jamadilawal 1434H<br> Saturday, 30th March 2013<br><p>
                </div>

            </div>



        </div>

    </body>
</html>


*{margin: 0 auto;}

#header{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

p{
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
}


#container{
 height: 50px;
 width: 800px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 20%
}


#apa{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: brown;
    left: 420px;
 }


#date{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zWpM9/

Comment: Can you recreate the issue you're having over on [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I edited the question and added a fiddle to it

Comment: included jsFiddle below

Answer (score 0):

most of the times, absolute positioning causes that. try not using absolute positioning

Comment: Thx @Mandar. I tried changing all position to relative but it still didnt resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

can't inherit the width based off the parent if the parent also not set, try

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}
```

also get rid of that `* { margin: auto; }` and only add it to things that MUST be centered.

Additional issues, you are using `#header { width: 100%; }` and then `#content { width: 800px; }` which is a poor idea. If header is smaller than 800px, what will content do? act strangely, and unexpectedly. So, please don't do this. Either specify all with percents or NONE (it will be easier for you as a beginner).

here is my fiddle, GUESSING what you might have wanted to do. It scales with zoom correctly, and uses no percentages.

http://jsfiddle.net/QgH99/

Comment: add width:100% to the container if you want that to be the case as well.